# How to Automate SMS from PHP mysql at Particular point of Time

Tags: php, mysql, sms

I have a website where people will book for Site visits.The Support Executive Confirms Site visit in the previous day. Once the Site visit is confirmed on the day on which site visit should happen the customer should receive SMS in morning telling that you have site visit today as requested.

I have Third party SMS Service

Now I Should Run a Code in PHP, MySQL which sends a SMS in the morning on which the site visit should happen

How can I Do that

Comment: Maybe you want to share some code so we can help?

Comment: sounds like you need a cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron -> starts PHP-Script , PHP Script reads records from the SQL Table and checks if an SMS has to be sent, i assume its sms over mail, so you can use the integrated php function to send out mails to the sms gateway. For the guy confirming the visits, create another site with proper authentication where he can access the table and agree with the site-visits and anotherone for the customer to register for site visits

Answer (score 1):

You need a cron job set to run in morning which will call your php file have code for looking in database for customers you need to send sms to.

Yo need to register to sum sms gateway provide 2 good one i know is clickatell and eztexting.

You can get there api for sending sms in there website.

Happy Smsing :D

Answer (score 0):

Set a Cron Jobs in your Control panel.Try this link 
http://www.devx.com/DevX/Article/39900/1954

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try an entirely different approach, check out:
Sent.ly - http://sent.ly

I am the founder of Sent.ly and thought maybe Sent.ly could help you out...

Sent.ly allows you to use an Android phone as an SMS gateway. So... you could just purchase a cheap Android phone ($150 or so) and set up Sent.ly on it and put a SIM in the phone.

By calling the Sent.ly API, the SMS would go out through the SIM in your Android phone. Sent.ly also has the option for scheduling an SMS for sending later which is your use case.

This also allows your PHP application to RECEIVE SMS in addition to just sending it out.

You can setup rules and if an incoming message matches a rule, it would be posted to a PHP page of your choice.

Since I am a great fan of stackoverflow, I would like to invite you to try Sent.ly. We would be happy to set you up with extra credits if you like. Just mail us at support@sent.ly

Cheers,

Varun

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a system like this for use with some of my clients, and you can easily use it to integrate with your website or applications, through HTTP POST or WebServices (using PHP, C# or whatever).

If you are interested just leave an email or other contact information as a reply to this answer and I will gladly send you a sample code of how to send SMS, setting the desired time for sending messages, beyond other things, through our system.

You will not need to have any kind of cron knowledge and setup, it is all handled by our system, and the code is pretty simple and straight forward. You will only need to call our services upon site visit confirmation, setting the desired message sending time, and our system will do the rest.

Best regards.